# Accessing Excel File Located at Properties.Resources and keep here template

Tags: c#, excel, resources, npoi

I have a big Excel file with multi sheets that I am using as a template to write data on and then save as a new file to disk. In debug mode, I read it from disk add data to it and save it in a different location without any problems. However, now I need to  creat release to my client, but I want to prevent him from reaching the file Excel... so I tried to add my excel file to the Resources but I cann't reread it becaus when I try to read from resources i get it like list of string and i cann't read the forme of template.

I used

> NPOI

for read/write the excel file.

So how can I open it from the Resources folder? Is there a better alternative for including such template files to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution and it work with me,

for use file Excel, it must already exist physically, so i saved excel file like temp file and i used this temp file for read my data,

```
string sPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sPath, Properties.Resources.data_base);
```

note: **Properties.Resources.data_base** this is my Excel file.

at the end I delete this temp file for more security

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(sPath ))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(sPath );
 }
```